# Retracts of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ be a non-empty set. Is $A$ a retract of $\mathbb{Q}$? In other words, is there a continuous map $r: \mathbb{Q}\to A$ such that $r|_A = \mathsf{id}_A$?

Comment: Not always, there is no such map when $A\neq \Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb Q$ for instance.

Comment: There's lots of partial answers. Yes if $A=[a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ where $a<b \in \mathbb{Q}$. No if $A$ is the set of dyadic rationals. Can you narrow the question down somewhat?

Comment: This is already sufficient @OlivierBégassat - can you post your thoughts (maybe with an argument why there is no such map if $A\neq \mathbb{Q}$ is dense)?

Comment: Because each retract of a Hausdorff space is its closed subspace. :-)